# FInding values from one column in another dataframe, and based on the value of other column flag it

Tags: python, dataframe, comparison

I have 2 dataframes as the ones from the picture below. I want to check the 2 dataframes and see if I can find any name from DF2 in DF1, if so then I want to check the status. If it is completed then I want to set value CLOSED in the column flag in DF2 for that specific name.

[image]

So far I did this part:

```
result = DF2['name'].isin(DF1['name']).astype(int)
```

However, I don't know how to set value in the flag column based on that condition mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`df2.flag = df1.merge(df2, on='name')['status_x'].map(lambda x: "Closed" if x == 'completed' else '')`